# How to add 2 Matrices together in OCAML without modules?

Tags: matrix, ocaml, addition, ml

I have made a **function** that checks for a **valid matrix**, a **function** that finds the **length of a list** and a **function** that states the **length of a row** and the **number of columns** in a matrix. What I need to know is how to write a **function** that **adds two matrices** together **WITHOUT MODULES**. I will show the **completed functions below**:

```
(* declaration of types intseq and intmatrix *)
type intseq = int list;;

type intmatrix = IM of intseq list;;

let getbody (IM x) = x;;

(* function getbody to retrieve the body of the intmatrix which is of type intseq list *)

let rec length: 'a list -> int =
  fun xs ->
  match xs with
    [] -> 0
  | (x::rest) -> 1 + length rest;;

(* test whether a list of lists of integers represents a matrix. 
   The length of each row should be equal.*)
let rec ismatrix x =

  match x with
    | IM([]) -> true
    | IM([[]]) -> true
    | IM([_]) -> true
    | IM(x::x2::rest) -> if (length x <> length x2)
        then false
        else ismatrix (IM(x2::rest));;

(* function matrixshape takes the matrix, and calculates the number of
   columns and rows *)
let rec matrixshape x =
  match x with
    | IM([]) -> (0,0)
    | IM([[]]) -> (0,0)
    | IM(x::rest) -> (length x,length rest + 1);;



(*A couple of extra functions I tried out \/ \/ \/*)
let rec seqadd : intseq -> intseq -> intseq =
  fun xs ys ->
  begin match xs, ys with
  | [], _ -> ys
  | _, [] -> xs
  | h::t, h2::t2 -> (h+h2)::(seqadd t t2)
  end;;

let rec rowadd: intseq list -> intseq list -> intseq list =
  fun row1 row2 ->
  match row1, row2 with
    | IM([[]]), IM([[_]]) -> row1
    | IM([[_]]), IM([[]]) -> row2
    | IM([[h::t]]), IM([[h2::t2]]) -> IM([[(h+h2)::(rowadd t t2)]]);;


(* matrix addition *)
let rec matrixadd: intmatrix -> intmatrix -> intmatrix =
  fun x y ->
(*TO DO*)
```

Comment: What do you mean "without modules"? You mean without the standard library? Can you tell where you are stuck, why you can't complete it? And maybe how you would do it "with modules'.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter I'm not allowed to use library functions such as 'List'.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter there is a Matrice module we are not allowed to use

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Please show us how you tried to write your function.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter Online examples use things like 'add-matrix' and 'make-matrix' just to easily create and use matrices

Comment: Right. But what is making you stuck? Is it that you don't know the definition of matrix addition?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter I know how matrix addition works, I just don't know how to do it in ocaml. I'm not very good with declaritive languages. I can't _think_ in OCAML. I know how to do certain things but I don't know if what I know can be put together to make matrix addition.

Comment: OCaml is not a "declarative" language. It is expression-based rather than statement-based, but still supports both functional and imperative programming. Anyway, you have to be more specific. Show us some code you've tried to solve the problem, and explain what specifically you are struggling to get right. That gives su an idea of what you understand and don't understand, since we can't very well explain the entire language to you in an answer. We're also not going to just write the code for you, since you'll learn nothing from that.

Answer (score 0):

I would break it down into a couple of simpler steps, as you started to do -- adding a single row, and adding multiple rows, eg.

```
let matrixadd m1 m2 =
  let rec addrow r1 r2 =
    match r1,r2 with
    | x :: x',  y :: y' -> x + y :: addrow x' y'
    | _                 -> []                     (* assume dims are correct *)
  in
  let rec addrows a b =
    match a,b with
    | r1 :: a', r2 :: b' -> addrow r1 r2 :: addrows a' b'
    | _                  -> []
  in
  let a, b = getbody m1, getbody m2 in
  IM (addrows a b)


(* example *)
let m1 = IM [[1;2]; [3;4]] in matrixadd m1 m1;;
(* - : intmatrix = IM [[2; 4]; [6; 8]] *)
```

Comment: Look how to merge `addrows` and `addrow` into single function. Just because I think it will be interesting for you =)

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that input matrices have the same size, you can use the following function.
It is implemented for matrix = `int list list`.

```ml
let add = 
  let rec add f a b = 
    match a, b with 
    | ah :: at, bh :: bt -> (f ah bh) :: (add f at bt)
    | [], []             -> []
    | _                  -> assert false
  in
  add (add (+))
```